# how to show only current month day in gridview?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-calendar

[image]
    here is the image and i want to show only current month days not next and not previous days.
here is my adapter code and i mange and set the days from adapter.and in class file i have set the adapter in gridview. can u please help?

package com.ManageMyTimeTableAdapter;

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.ManageMyTimeTable.CalendarView;
import com.ManageMyTimeTable.DaliyScreenActivity;
import com.ManageMyTimeTable.DateUtils;
import com.ManageMyTimeTable.R;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Date[] calendarGrid;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private static Calendar mCal;   
private String today;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

public CalendarAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    CalendarView.dateStore.clear();
    initCalendar(mCal);     
}   
private void initCalendar(Calendar cal){

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(cal.getTime());
    c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);

    int startOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Log.e("fdfdfdf",""+startOfWeek);
    Log.e("-1 vagar nu",""+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -startOfWeek);

    calendarGrid = new Date[6 * 7];
    int gridCount = 0;
    for (int week = 0; week < 6; week++) {
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
            Date dt = c.getTime();
            dt.setHours(0);
            dt.setMinutes(0);
            dt.setSeconds(0);
            calendarGrid[gridCount++] = dt;
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
        }
    }

public void nextMonth() {

    mCal.set(mCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, mCal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    initCalendar(mCal);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void prevMonth() {

    mCal.set(mCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1, mCal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    initCalendar(mCal);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Calendar getCurrentCalendar() {
    return mCal;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return calendarGrid.length;
}

@Override
public Date getItem(int position) {
    return calendarGrid[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_my_calendar, null);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCalDate);
        holder.txtEventCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventCount);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Date date = getItem(position);

    holder.txtDate.setText(String.format("%2d", date.getDate()));
    holder.txtDate.setTag(format.format(date).toString());
    String keyDate = DateUtils.formatDate(DateUtils.DB_DATE_FORMAT, date);
    setStyle(keyDate, position, holder.txtDate, convertView);

    if(CalendarView.dateStore.size()>= position+1){

        Log.d(" Calender Adapter "," Clear arrayList ****  "+CalendarView.dateStore.size());
        CalendarView.dateStore.clear();         
    }       
    CalendarView.dateStore.add(format.format(date).toString());     
    return convertView;
}

private void setStyle(String dateKey, int position, TextView txt, View convertView){

    if (dateKey.equals(today))
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#88D23218"));
    else
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#88CCCCCC"));

    if (getItem(position).getMonth() != mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF787878"));
    else

        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

        if(DaliyScreenActivity.month_member_id_arr.contains(txt.getText().toString())){             

            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(230, 187, 60));               
        }       
    }   
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtDate;
    TextView txtEventCount;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getView` method ...Change your last `if..else`

to this,

```
 if (getItem(position).getMonth() != mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
 {
        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF787878"));
 }
 else
 {
        txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

          if(DaliyScreenActivity.month_member_id_arr.contains(txt.getText().toString())){             

            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(230, 187, 60));               
        }       
 }
```

I mean to say keep your code to change background to Yellow in the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

Check, where the cells which are not in the current month get set their grey text color and either set the text color to the same color as the background or even better set empty text for those cells.

```
if (getItem(position).getMonth() != mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#88CCCCCC"));
```

or

```
if (getItem(position).getMonth() != mCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    txt.setText("");
```

Comment: hey Ridcully thanks for getting hint..its worked but not exactly so i can solve using different trial. i can focous here now.so thanks again